# Two conflicting forms of equation of state of non-relativistic gas

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, statistical-mechanics

I've run into two conflicting derivations of the equation of state of a non-relativistic gas.  However, the derivations of the relativistic equation of state of both sources agree.  I think maybe the discrepancy is due to different definitions of energy (thermodynamics versus...?)  I've summarized the arguments below.

$\textbf{Source 1}$: Stellar Structure & Evolution notes by O.R. Pols, page 24
http://www.astro.ru.nl/~onnop/education/stev_utrecht_notes/chapter1-4.pdf

Start with the pressure integral, 
$$ P = \frac{1}{3} \int_0^{\infty} \mathop{dp} n(p) p v_p = \frac{1}{3}n\langle pv_p\rangle,   $$
where $n(p)$ is the distribution function in momentum, $p$ is the momentum, and $v_p$ is the velocity of a particle with momentum $p$.  Also, recall that the "internal energy density" $u$ is 
$$ u = \int_0^{\infty}\mathop{dp} n(p) E_p = n \langle E_p \rangle,      $$
where $E_p$ is the kinetic energy.

For the non-relativistic case, $v_p = \frac{p}{m}$, so
$$   P = \frac{1}{3} n \langle pv_p \rangle = \frac{1}{3} n \langle \frac{p^2}{m} \rangle $$
$$ =  \frac{1}{3} n \langle 2E_p \rangle  = \frac{2}{3} u, $$
so the conclusion is that 
$$ P = \frac{2}{3} u.$$

$\textbf{Source 2}$: Ryden's $\textit{Introduction to Cosmology}$, page 55.

Equations of state here are denoted 
$$ P = w\varepsilon,$$ where $\textbf{I am assuming that Ryden's $\varepsilon$ is the same as Pols' $u$}$.
Non-relativistic gas obeys the ideal gas law,
$$ P = \frac{\rho}{\mu}kT,$$
where $\rho$ is the density and $\mu$ is the mean mass of the particles.  For non-relativistic particles, 
$$ \varepsilon \approx \rho ,$$
so
$$ P \approx \frac{kT}{\mu}\varepsilon $$

For a non-relativistic gas, 
$$ 3kT = \mu \langle v^2 \rangle     $$
and thus
$$  P = \frac{\langle v^2 \rangle}{3} \epsilon,   $$
but where she claims
$$\frac{\langle v^2 \rangle}{3} \ll 1,$$ which is clearly at odds with Pols' claim that that proportionality factor is $\frac{2}{3}$.  In fact, Ryden takes the proportionality to be $0$, so that $P=0$ for a non-relativistic gas.

I am wondering how to reconcile these two arguments.  Are Pols' $u$ and Ryden's $\varepsilon$ the same "type" of energy?

Comment: You are correct , I did the numbers and cannot make that term disappear, so I erased my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivation by Pols is correct. Ryden makes the strange decision to plug the relativistic rest energy $\varepsilon = \rho c^2$ into the classical ideal gas law. Surely it makes more sense to define a classical kinetic energy
$$
u = \frac{1}{2}\rho\langle v^2\rangle
$$
so that
$$
P = \frac{2kTu}{\mu\langle v^2\rangle} = \frac{2}{3}u.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I actually found this derivation in a stat mech book later.  
I know, however, that it is common in cosmology to discuss "cold dust" equations of state, which are just as Ryden described, $P=0$.  I'm still not quite sure how to reconcile that with the derivation you provided.  Is it just that $u=0$ too, because maybe $u$ is just internal $\textit{kinetic}$ energy density (ie, not rest mass energy), and for cold non-relativistic matter, $\langle v^2 \rangle \approx 0$ to first approximation?